# Why am I getting the NoMethodError 'undefined method `source'' after running the gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. I am using the newest version of Ruby, Rails and RubyMine and I would like to run the gemfile with RubyMine. But I am getting the following NoMethodEffor:

```
{location}:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `source' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The error occurred by running the line

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

of the gemfile.

These are my installed gems with the current version number:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.10)
actionpack (3.0.10)
activemodel (3.0.10)
activerecord (3.0.10)
activeresource (3.0.10)
activesupport (3.0.10)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.1, 2.0.10)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.18)
columnize (0.3.4)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
haml (3.1.2)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.3.0, 2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (2.5.0, 1.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.2, 1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.8.2, 0.6.14)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.0.10)
railties (3.0.10)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.9.2, 2.5.8)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.28)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta5)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (1.8.8)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)
```

Can you explain why I am getting this error?  What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you please post the command you are trying to execute?

Comment: I don't try any command on the console. I run the gemfile with RubyMine. So you can select the option 'Run Gemfile' und take run. After that the error occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with RubyMine but surely you don't have to execute Gemfile. If you're trying to install new gems you have to execute bundler in your root directory. I don't know if RubyMine has something for that. See http://gembundler.com/rationale.html for further information